# How to use vue3 in cdn mode, how to use jsx syntax？

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want to use vue3 in cdn mode, and use jsx syntax to develop, how to configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use CDN with `Template`

Similar solution to what you want to achieve.

```js
// CDN Vue Import
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const msg = ref("hello world")
    
    return { msg }
  },
  template: `
    <div>{{ msg }}</div>
    <input v-model="msg" />
  `
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer，but I want to use jsx not template, when I use jsx, But in the browser it will report an error..  like this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Yes, because you would need to use Babel.

Comment: Since you requested the answer using CDN, I assume you won't be using Node.js, npm package manager, Vite, etc. to configure Babel (which works well with React by default) for Vue. Therefore, I believe this is not a viable question, so I suggested an alternative. Since I don't know why it has to be this way, I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: thankyou, yes, Is it impossible to configure babel in cdn mode?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Babel cannot be configured in a CDN mode. You need a processor like webpack, Rollup, or Vite, etc., for that purpose.